# How to transpose a dataframe down with a dynamic list of variables in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
store   store_name   2016-01-01   2016-01-02  ...
1       abc          ###          ###
```

That I would like to transpose down:

```
store   store_name  date          sales
1       abc         2016-01-01    ###
1       abc         2016-01-02    ###
```

The difficulty that I'm having is that the number of descriptive store variables can vary. When they are static I can transpose it down with a step like:

```
library(tidyr)

gather(store_sales, 
       date,
       sales,
       -c(store, store_name))
```

But trying to account for when there are a different amount is proving tricky. So for example could be store, store_name and store_name2 - is there a way to pass a variable into the gather function to make the statement dynamic?

I have tried a couple of things, but can't get it to work

```
vars <- paste0("store_sales, 
         date,
         sales,
         -store, 
         -store_name")

store_sales_down <- gather(vars)
```

Comment: So you want all columns that are not a date, right?

Comment: Yes, all columns that are not a date (they are all in format yyyy-mm-dd) I want to be left from transposing down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `gather_` function allows strings to be passed:

Make the data

```
d <- data.frame(store = 1,
                store_name = "abc",
                "2016-01-01" = 2,
                "2016-01-02" = 5,
                "2016-01-03" = 87,
                check.names = FALSE)
```

Perform the operation:

```
library(tidyr)
gather_(d, key_col = c("date"), 
        value_col = "sales", 
        gather_cols= grep("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", names(d), value = TRUE))

store store_name       date sales
1     1        abc 2016-01-01     2
2     1        abc 2016-01-02     5
3     1        abc 2016-01-03    87
```

Now with an extra column:

```
d$storename2 = 3

gather_(d, key_col = c("date"), 
        value_col = "sales", 
        gather_cols= grep("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", names(d), value = TRUE))

  store store_name storename2       date sales
1     1        abc          3 2016-01-01     2
2     1        abc          3 2016-01-02     5
3     1        abc          3 2016-01-03    87
```